# Building my own Docker image from officiall Wordpress image

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, volumes

I’m trying to build my own image based on image from Docker Hub
What I want to do is to add some new files to existing file system on image
I created Dockerfile with the following content:

**from wordpress**

**copy . /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins**

Here I’m trying to fetch official wordpress image and then copy some files in my current directory to plugins folder. Then I built the image and got new image lets call it newimage. Then I’m trying to run container based on this newimage and also I want to use volume for this contatiner to store data on my host machine. I’m doing this command:

**docker run -d --name wp -v wp-volume:/var/www/html newimage**

The container starts well but when I’m trying to check the folder var/www/html/wp-content/plugins I can’t see the files that was copied on stage of building this image. But if I do the command:
**docker run -d --name wp newimage**
without using a volume I can see the files that was copied in the path /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
so why if i run container WITH volume I can’t see my files but If I run container WITHOUT volume I can see my files in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins

Answer (score 1):

When you mount a volume to a directory in the container, all the contents in that directory is replaced with the volume contents.

In your case, you mount your volume on /var/www/html. That means that all existing content in your image under that path, i.e. your plugin, becomes hidden and inaccessible.

Unfortunately you can't 'merge' the existing image content with the content of the volume. A good habit to get into is to always mount volumes on empty directories in the image so you don't accidentally hide content.

Comment: The documentation states the opposite: 
 If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as /app/ above),
 the directory’s contents are copied into the volume. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container
 and it works for me. Now the issue is that if I use bind mount instead of volume I get a new directory with the files but in that directory **the files that have been added during 
 image build with COPY command are not presented** but other files are presented

Comment: Are you sure the volume doesn't exist when you start it? Try doing `docker volume rm wp-volume` first to make sure that it doesn't.

Comment: I understand the difference between volume and bind mount my question  is why in my case there are no files that I've added during image build COPY presented in my directory that was mounted with -v /my-host-dir:/var/www/html but the files from initial image wordpress are presented. But if I use volume -v my-volume:/var/www/html all the files are presented (initial files from wordpress image and the files that was added with COPY command). I want to build my own image from wordpress image and add one folder to /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins but I can't run it with bind mount only with volume

Comment: when i run container i use unique name for volume every time -v unique-name:/var/www/html I don't understand why it doesn't copy ALL the content to mounted directory when I use -v host-direcotry:/var/www/html it copies ONLY initial content from folder /var/www/html and skips the content that was added during image build. But if I enter the container - exec -it container bash I can see all the files and the content that I've added during image build. So something happens when it mounts container folder to host folder but it works in case of volumes.

Comment: When I test it with a fresh volume, it copies the content from the image into the volume.

Comment: Yes it works in case of volumes but not in case of bind mounts. In case of bind mounts it copies only initial content not the content that was add with COPY command

Comment: But isn't that as documented? A volume will copy the content, if the volume is new. A bind mount will never copy it.